# Cannot install JModelica on Ububtu

Tags: jmodelica

I am following the installation procedure [here](https://svn.jmodelica.org/trunk/INSTALL).

I get the following error

```
find: ‘Assimulo’: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: line 3: cd: /home/akshay/Downloads/JModelica/build  /Assimulo_build/Assimulo: No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Makefile:1006: recipe for target 'build-python-packages' failed
make[2]: *** [build-python-packages] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/akshay/Downloads/JModelica/build'
Makefile:427: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/akshay/Downloads/JModelica/build'
Makefile:352: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been a problem for long time. You need to download the source for Assimulo in the 'external' directory as Assimulo. Even with it. I haven't been able to get JModelica to test successfully with Casadi. Code can't find NLPSolver.